# In Task Scheduler, can you pass a PHP url path with blank space like this?

Tags: php, automation, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have taken on someones project that has automation using Task Scheduler, while I am more familiar with cron jobs. One thing they did and I am yet to figure out if working properly, they have many running tasks that appended manufacturer numbers at the end, but with a space like so...

```
...\scrape_asc.php 5
```

while the original working task is...

```
...\scrape_asc.php
```

I just want to confirm if this is unique for Task Scheduler or the guy who did this tried something that simply cannot work like so. If this is common, then what would be the alternative for cron or regular url as obviously a space would never work. I can go through and debug, but it is very long script with ton's of spaghetti code tied in. I really just want to take these processes out of the equation if impossible for them to be working in the first place.

Btw, I have attempted to copy and test, but the concern is if Task Scheduler is only showing me an abstract of the code and functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For task scheduler, it'd be running PHP in command-line mode, so the `5` would simply be a command line argument, retrievable via the `argv` array.

Comment: so would scrape_asc.php?id=5 be the cron equivalent? Or is it specific to something other than id?

Comment: no. http-type query strings do not work on the command line. cron would be looking for a file which literally has `?id=5` in the filename. if you're dealing with command line, you have to use standard command line argument semantics. you could have `scrape_asc.php id=5`, pull out the id=5 from `argc`, then use the standard url parsing functions to decompose it to a normal key/value array like $_GET has.